# How to enable blueprint rest routes on sails app created with --minimal

Tags: sails.js

I'm new to sails, using 1.0.

I created an app with the --minimal command line switch and now I wish to add in some functionality.

I've already successfully added the ORM functionality (by adding `sails-hook-orm`, config/datasources and config/models.

Now I wish to enable the automatic blueprint routes. I've already added config/blueprint like so:

```
module.exports.blueprints = {
  prefix: '/api/v1',
  actions: true,
  rest: true,
  // shortcuts: true,
};
```

Now, if I manually add in the routes and actually write the standalone actions, for example, like below:

'GET /api/v1/users/:id': { action: 'users/find-one' },

It works. But I was expecting that blueprint would abstract those away from me when I set `rest: true` on the config...

What else should I check?

Answer (score 0):

By the [documentation](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/blueprints/blueprint-routes) is just put rest as true (is true by default), and this should work, seem like you have missing something else. Check if you have your controller created and your model with the same name.

- controllers

  - UserController.js
- models

  - User.js

If you don't have the controller created then the blueprint is not going to work